# Ошибка при парсинге HTML страницы в Android

Tags: java, android, json, парсер

Мне необходимо получить два значения конкретных значения с сайта, у каждого значения свой уникальный тег. Все это получается в программе для Windows, но при попытке повторить тоже самое на Android, приложение вылетает и говорит, что ошибка в этой строке:

```
Document document = Jsoup.connect("ссылка").get();
```

Не могу понять в чем заключается ошибка.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: F    ATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-402
Process: com.example.gekab.directtask, PID: 8843
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:464)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)
at om.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.cre    ateNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433)
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295)
at com.example.gekab.directtask.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:89)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
Caused by: android.system.GaiException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NOD    ATA (No address associated with hostname)
at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(N    ative Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29) 
at om.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.cre    ateNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248) 
at om.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
at om.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295) 
at com.example.gekab.directtask.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:89) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: android_getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
at libcore.io.Posix.android_getaddrinfo(N    ative Method) 
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.android_getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55) 
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:451) 
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252) 
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.Network$1.resolveInetAddresses(Network.java:29)    at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:188) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:157) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:100) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.cre    ateNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:357)      at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)    at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:433) 
at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:746) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:722) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:306) 
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:295) 
at com.example.gekab.directtask.MainActivity$2.run(MainActivity.java:89) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
D/EGL_emul    ation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xae4d4660: ver 3 1 (tinfo 0xae4d2e50)
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae649e60
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnim    ators on 0xaa059a00 (MenuPopupWindow$MenuDropDownListView) with handle 0xae631530
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xae649820
```

Comment: приведите Traceback ошибки, мы гадать не умеем

Comment: еще бы знать что это такое и где это брать

Comment: это сама ошибка, которая выводится в консоли

Comment: сюда не входит, куда можно скинуть?

Comment: добавьте в ваш вопрос, отредактируйте

Comment: я добавил только то, что было выделено красным

Comment: internet permission в манифесте прописан?

Comment: это прописал: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>